# define torch.cuda.LongTensor instead of torch.LongTensor

Tags: python, pytorch

When I run the following code the variable type turns into torch.LongTensor.  How can I have this create a torch.cuda.LongTensor instead?

```
# Turn string into list of longs
def char_tensor(string):
   tensor = torch.zeros(len(string)).long()
   for c in range(len(string)):          
      tensor[c] = all_characters.index(string[c])
   return Variable(tensor)

print(char_tensor('abcDEF'))
```

output:

```
Variable containing:
 10
 11
 12
 39
 40
 41
[torch.LongTensor of size 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer:

```
# Turn string into list of longs
def char_tensor(string):
   tensor = torch.zeros(len(string)).long()
   for c in range(len(string)):          
      tensor[c] = all_characters.index(string[c])
   return Variable(tensor).cuda()

print(char_tensor('abcDEF'))
```